# Grape API is removing '+' from string (replacing with blank space)

Tags: grape-api

I have a grape API and as part of a POST request I am passing a string that has a '+' as part of it (it's a phone number). Grape seems to be removing the `+` and replacing it with a blank space.

```
module V1
  class CustomerDetails < Grape::API
    before do
      error!("Unauthorized", 401) unless authenticated?
    end

    resource :customer_details do

      desc 'Update customer number'
      post anchor: false do
        params do
          requires :customer_id, type: String
          requires :customer_number, type: String
        end

        # Current behaviour: 
        # params[:customer_number] here will be ' 441920765847'

        # Expected behaviour: 
        # params[:customer_number] here will be '+441920765847'

      end
    end
  end
end
```

I expect to use postman to make the http POST request, with the parameter `customer_number` with value `+441920765847`and it does not lose the `+` (i.e. does not show as `441920765847`.

Answer (score 0):

solved! It was postman removing it because i was sending it in the params (url string) and not in the body